# Using templates in Go lang gives "Uncaught Syntax Error"

Tags: javascript, go

I'm trying to create a simple server in Go. I have it set up so that it will show me a page when I make a GET request to "/".

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", serveHomePage)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}

func serveHomePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    homePageTemplate, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
    if err == nil {
        homePageTemplate.Execute(w, nil)
    } else {
        panic("Something went wrong with the template!")
    }
}
```

I have my `index.html` in the same folder as my `server.go` file.
My directory looks like this:

```
.
├── index.html
├── scripts
│   ├── jquery.min.js
│   └── main.js
├── server.go
└── styles
    └── main.css
```

And my `index.html` has:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="urlSubmitForm">
            <input type="url">
            <button type="submit">Submit URL!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="./scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I am getting says,

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` on line 1 of my `main.js` file and line 1 of the `jquery.min.js` file.

If I click on the error, it points to the first line of my `index.html` file.

For reference (though I think this isn't relevant), here is my main.js file.

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {

});
```

Comment: Look at your browser's Network developer tab to see what those HTTP requests are returning; it's probably an HTML-formatted error.

Comment: @Pointy I just checked. Both my `.js` files are returning my HTML file. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I don't know; I was just suggesting that that would peel back a layer of the mystery.

Comment: Try to change `template.ParseFiles("index.html")` to `template.ParseFiles(r.URL)`

Comment: @KoshVery That doesn't work because ParseFiles requires a string argument

Comment: My bad, `r.URL.Path`. The idea is that you're passing there `index.html`, but should pass the requested uri e.g.  `scripts/main.js`.

Comment: It's always returning your index.html because that's exactly what you've programmed it to do: you've configured a handler for the route `"/"` (all requests) to always respond with the result of executing the template `index.html` (which, as a side note, doesn't appear to be a template, so the template parsing is unnecessary).

Comment: @MickeyTheMouse you need to setup a [file serving handler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer_stripPrefix) for your Go server. Something like `http.HandleFunc("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/"))`.